# Дублируются записи

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

Подскажите где ошибся

есть ресурсы

каталог

```
-авто

 --мазда

-мебель

 --диан

 --кресло
```

мне нужно вывести все подпункты мебели

делаю вывод так

```
[[!getPage?
                      &elementClass=`modSnippet`
                      &element=`getResources`
                      &showHidden=`1`
                      &tpl=`cat_list`
                      &limit=`5`
                      &includeContent=`1`
                      &includeTVs=`1`
                      &processTVs=`1`
                      &tvPrefix=``
                      &parents=`[[*id]]`
                      &hideContainers=`1`
                      &pageLimit=`5`
                      &pageNavVar=`page.nav`
                    ]]

                 <div class="pagination-block">
                    <ul class="pagination" te>
                    [[!+page.nav:notempty=`
                    [[!+page.nav]]

                    `]]
                    </ul>
                </div>

 [[!getResources? 
 &parents=`[[*id]]` 
 &depth=`0` 
 &tpl=`blockcat` 
 &includeContent=`1`
 &includeTVs=`1`
        &processTVs=`1`
        &tvPrefix=``
 ]]


<div class="col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 list-item">
  <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-6 li-title"><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-4 col-xs-4 li-descr">Масла и химия</div>
  <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-2 col-xs-4 like-com">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><span> [[!TicketCommentsCount? &Id=`[[*id]]`]]</span>

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span><span>[[+likeDislike]]</span>

  </div>

  <img src="[[+imgF]]">
  <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-6 intr-text">
    <ul>
      <li>[[+city]] [[+adress]]</li>
      <li> [[+mts]] [[+velc]] [[+lif]]</li>
      <li>[[+work]]</li>
      <li>[[+site]]</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

если в мебели 1 подпункт то выводит один, а если как я указал два, то он выводит каждый подпункт по 2 раза

Comment: разобрался сам!

Comment: Тогда удали вопрос, если он больше не актуален.